# Microsoft azure app service(MVC C# Web API) getting sleep if there is no action in some interval time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

We have use Microsoft Azure shared web api hosting, but it getting sleep if there is no actions in that api(no api call from mobile app in some interval time),

Once it getting sleep then it will take long time for give the response.

usually one api is give response in 125 milliseconds but long time no action in between the api and mobile app it will getting sleep, that time the same api take 2 minutes for give response or give the timeout exception.

App engine running in Share hosting model

How to resolve that, Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 'by design' for the Shared App Service. If you want to use Always on, move to Basic (or higher) tier.

> **Always On.**
>   By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous WebJobs or runs WebJobs triggered using a CRON expression, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

Source: [Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure)

Answer (score 2):

If your application uses **Application Insights**, you could [configure a ping test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability) to ensure your API stays warm (the Always On feature basically does the same). 
Alternative you could use **Azure Scheduler** to invoke your API periodically.

---

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior for Shared pricing tiers. If you want your app to keep alive you need **Always on** enabled which is available starting from Basic pricing. Otherwise app pool will be always recycled after some period of inactivity (about 21 minutes).